# Testing drag and drop in ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I am trying to test a UI that has the ability to drag and drop. All im looking to do is to drag an element to another element on the page. The code is below.

```
it 'should drag and drop' do                
    draggable = @driver.find('//*[@id="2"]').first
    droppable = @driver.find('//*[@id="dropmembers4"]').first
    draggable.drag_to(droppable)
    @driver.find('//div[contains(., "Dropped!")]').should_not be_nil    
end
```

Currently im getting an error:

```
Failure/error: draggable = @driver.find('//*[@id="2"]').first
No method error: undefined method 'find' for nil:NilClass
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: you obviously failed to initialize `@driver` variable, can you please post how you define it?

Comment: As you have guessed im pretty new to this. This is how im trying to define it, @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox. But im getting an error uninitialized constant selenium. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `@driver` variable does not exist, that mean the initialization is not working. Here's the minimal initialization code:

```
$ [sudo] gem install selenium
$ selenium install
```

And the code for using it:

```
require 'selenium'
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome)
```

And if you're using bundler to define dependencies, you should run:

```
$ bundle install
```

And then this code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'selenium'
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome)
```

Comment: Please keep us posted about this issue